# How to detect the border of the screen and bounce back?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
            if (bucket.x > 0) {
                rect.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            }
            if (rect.x < 0) {
                rect.x = 0;
                rect.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            }

            if (rect.x > Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth() - 30) {
                rect.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            }
```

I have a rectangle, it has a width of 30 px, I want to move from it's x point till the edge of the screen, when it gets there I want it to go back to the other edge. it's only moving till it hits one edge and it stops.

This might be a basic question but I'm new to Libgdx and I can't find documentation. If I add a `while (true )` loop the app would stop working. Basically I want it to move infinitely along the x axis back and forth from right edge to the left edge.

I tried something like

```
`if (rect.x > 800 - 30) `
```

it won't work either and I don't like specifying the width of the device explicitly. Basically it's moving but never detecting the right edge of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move by a determined speed your rectangle **once** a loop.

```
// In your declaration
float speed = 15; // Pixels / second

// In your game loop
rect.x += speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

When you reach the edge of the screen, you need your speed to become the **opposite** of your current speed

```
// Check if rectangle is out of screen
if (rect.x + rect.width > screenWidth || rect.x < 0)
{
    speed = -speed;
}
```

That's it, and it works exactly the same for Y

Comment: You shouldn't define your speed as `pixels / second` sine this will make your game play different in different window sizes unless you use a viewport. But if you use a viewport I argue that you should have your viewport in an abstract unit instead of pixels (for example meters).

Answer (score 1):

In order to simulate physical event (bounce, collision..) you can use Box2d module from LibGDX. instead of calculating the transformation you define the object, apply a force and see it applies to your objects.